# Auto SafeApp detection

Tags: gnosis-safe

I want to write a SafeApp. Manifest and WalletConnect are already working, but now i want to use the Web3 SafeAppProvider. Normally a user first has to click on connect and select the correct provider.

My Question: Is there a way, like checking for a global variable or whatever that lets me know IF i am called via SafeApp, so I can default provider selection to SafeAppProvider?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to inject global variables into an iframe so it's a little bit trickier than we would like it to be, but here is what you can do:

1. You can check that the app is running inside an iframe
2. Initialize the SDK and fire a method to get the Safe info with a timeout:

```
 public async isSafeApp(): Promise<boolean> {
   // check if we're in an iframe
   if (window?.parent === window) {
     return false;
   }

   const safe = await Promise.race([
       sdk.safe.getInfo(),
       new Promise<undefined>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200)),
     ]);;

   return !!safe;
 }
```